# R ggbio plotIdeogram error

Tags: r, bioconductor

I was running the ideogram example on pages 20, 22 of the [ggbio Introduction and quick start page.](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/vignettes/ggbio/inst/doc/ggbio.pdf) 
The line

```
p.ideo <-plotIdeogram(genome="hg19")
```

gives this result.

```
Loading...
Error: Expectation failed
```

After some initial errors with the "TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene" package (returning "error: object '.setDummyField' not found" which is a compatibility issue between 3.0.0 and 3.0.1), I installed R 3.0.1 and reinstalled all the packages I needed. ggbio which was not loading properly in R 3.0.0 loaded properly here.

I have full and reduce tracks of the figure on p.22, but the top ideogram is blank. Is there a way to obtain that ideogram?